# Why is Strömberg Wavelet section in 2018 book an amost exact copy of 2016 Wikipedia article?

Tags: wavelets, publishing

Does anyone know why [Section 2.10 Strömberg Wavelet](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN9781839473401&pg=PA51) of the 2018 book [Wavelet: Analysis and Methods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/178882122X) seems to be an almost exact copy of the [2016 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Str%C3%B6mberg_wavelet&oldid=745698914) of the same name?

There are some small differences:

- The book section is missing citations while the Wikipedia article cites [Strömberg (1983)](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN9780534980412&pg=PA475) and [Wojtaszczyk (1997)](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN9780521578943).
- The book at one point appears to mis-typeset $P^{(m)}(V)$ as $P(m)(V)$

The Wikipedia article does not cite the book (which would be difficult anyway given the 2016 versus 2018 timestamps). The book meanwhile claims "[All rights reserved.](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN9781839473401&pg=PR4)", and a [Google Book search](https://books.google.com/books?id=q-PEDwAAQBAJ&q=Wikipedia#v=onepage&q=Wikipedia&f=false) of the book for "Wikipedia" returns "No results found in this book for Wikipedia".

Comment: Is this a math question?  I don't think we are a good forum in which to resolve authorship claims.

Comment: @lulu : Which forum is more likely to yield an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: @JohnBentin  I have no idea.  I suggest referring the matter to Wikipedia and letting them handle it, if they care to,

Comment: My guess is that either Carmen Hurley or Jaden Maclean wrote the Wikipedia article, kept it on file, and reproduced it in their book (minus the LaTeX formatting).

Comment: @JohnBentin—Even if one of them did write the article, wouldn't the 2018 book copyright put Wikipedia in legal jeopardy? (provided no CC-BY type licensing to Wikipedia involved).

Comment: @DanielJ.Greenhoe : Wikipedia is a nonprofit organization, with its content provided by volunteers. By sending your work to be published on Wikipedia, you are essentially donating it to the public, and anyone may reproduce it freely.

Comment: Section 2.11 looks like a copy of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_wavelet.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of this book's publisher and, searching for the authors, couldn't find a university page or anything (as a matter of fact, this and one other book seem to be their only meaningful trace on the internet - and I believe their names are sufficiently rare to where one should be able to stumble upon at least *some* mention of their work). Unless I'm terribly mistaken, all this suggests it may indeed be a predatory publication, trying to earn a quick buck on a poorly produced textbook. This is only a conjecture, however, and should be treated as such. Whether there is any point in pursuing this matter further depends entirely on your own disposition and availability of resources. In either case, emailing the publisher about it should be a good first step.

Comment: The preface to the book is revealing. In its entirety it reads: “The scope of food microbiology is vast and spreading very rapidly. The study of microorganisms which have both positive and negative effects on the quality and safety of raw and processed foods. [sic] $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ —Carmen Hurley $\qquad$  Jaden Maclean ”